# Creating a JTable from multiple Array lists

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtable

In a class called database; there are **three** `String` `ArrayList`s named *firstName*, *surname* and *gender*. The elements in the `ArrayList`s are parallel. For example *surname*(1) would be the surname of *firstName*(1).

I would like to know how to display these `ArrayList`s in a `JTable`. All `ArrayList`s being shown in different columns.

Comment: This could be solved by reading through [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), referencing the JavaDocs and search SO...Vote to close

Answer (score 1):

- Use a DefaultTableModel
- Set that model to the table
- Use `addRow` which takes an `Object[]` or `Vector` argument to add rows to the model

---

```
String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Surname", "Gender"};
DeafultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then add your lists

```
List<String> firstnames = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> genders = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < firstname.size(); i++){
    Object[] row = { firstnames.get(i), suenames.get(i), genders.get(i) };
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

See: [DefaultTableModel javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) | [How to use Tables tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

> The elements in the ArrayLists are parallel.

Why? Create a custom `Person` that contains those 3 properties. Then you add the `Person` object to the ArrayList. Then you can create a proper TableModel that displays the `Person` object.

You can check out the [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a more general solution. The `JButtonTableModel.java` example code will give you an idea of how you can customize the model for your Person class.

Or you can use the examples from the Swing tutorial to create a completely custom PersonTableModel.

Comment: The reason that I am not doing tat is because this is a database that the user can edit from the program.

Comment: @user3144389, that is no reason. There is no reason the data in the Person object can't be updated. You just add a setter method. I gave you a working example.